# Долгая инициализация php скрипта

Tags: php

есть 2 сервера (Ubuntu 16.04) конфигурация примерно одинаковая, но одном сервере php -v отрабатывает моментально, но втором с секундной задержкой, php.ini идентичны
Как можно разобраться, что мешает запуску?

Comment: А как вы поняли что выполняется с задержкой? Машины виртуальные или разные тачки физически?  Вы делали `ping` с этих машин?

Comment: оба инстанса в амазоне, пинг идентичный

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос снят, не заметил, что в "проблемном" php в конфиге была подключена browscap

```
browscap = /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/browscap.ini
```